# How to dump the setup without record of odoo?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-11

I installed one module and create number of record. After that i created some field through admin and added that field to that model. Apart from this i updated several things from admin side. Now i want to dump all setup  for production, but i do not want that dummy data.

After that i also want push that all setup to git. So how can i do that?

Also try below command for restore, but it's not working.

```
pg_restore -d databse -U username -C /opt/Test.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Customization made from the admin panel of Odoo is stored in database tables, for example, `view, models, actions, fields` in tables like `ir_ui_view, ir_model_data, ir_window_actions` and numerous tables in DB. To dump without dummy records, what you can do is restore full database with respective dummy records table for example if your records were from Contact module, restore full database without `res_partner` table.

This way, your database will contain all of the customization but none of the dummy records you created for testing. But the challenge is to isolate all the tables you have created records on, as many modules are interrelated and creating record on one module creates record on related table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dump without data you can use

```
pg_dump -h <host_if_remote> -p <if_different_port> -U your_user -s schema_only > filename.dump
```

And if you try to restore it you can use `psql` command.

```
psql -U your_user -d your_db -f filename.dump
```